# SQL remove duplicates - keep the row with least missing value, and fill missing value from duplicate rows if any non-missing value exists

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table:

| id | gender | county | dob |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | male | USA | NULL |
| 001 | male | NULL | NULL |
| 002 | female | FRANCE | NULL |
| 002 | NULL | NULL | 28/01/1990 |

There are lots of duplicates that I'd like to remove based on column id. I want to keep the record with the least missing value, and at the same time fill missing values from other duplicated records.

Expected query output:

| id | gender | county | dob |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | male | USA | NULL |
| 002 | female | FRANCE | 28/01/1990 |

How can I do this in MySQL?

Comment: Imagine that there are 2 different non-NULL values in some column for the same `id`. How to select one of them?

Answer (score 2):

You may try aggregating by the `id` and taking the max of all other columns:

```sql
SELECT id, MAX(gender) AS gender, MAX(country) AS country, MAX(dob) AS dob
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY id;
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. However my actual table has way more columns than this simplified example (around 50 columns in total). is there a way not to mention all columns name?

Comment: Sadly you might have to mention all column names explicitly.  At least, my approach would require that.

Comment: @crx91 *is there a way not to mention all columns name?* No. But you may get the columns names from INFORMATION_SCHEMA, build the query text and execute it as prepared statement.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT CONCAT('SELECT id,',
              GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('MAX(',
                                  COLUMN_NAME,
                                  ') ',
                                  COLUMN_NAME)
                           ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION),
              ' FROM test GROUP BY id')
INTO @sql
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE()
  AND TABLE_NAME = 'test'
  AND COLUMN_NAME <> 'id';

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DROP PREPARE stmt;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c7deccefdcbaf2422bc177fb349ad080

Use this code in a batch (from the program - enable multi-query) or in stored procedure.

Replace `id` with real identifying column name (3 places).

Replace `test` with real table name (2 places).

Remove `ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION` if you do not need the output columns order to match the order in source table (but `id` will be always the first).

Replace `DATABASE()` with definite database name if needed.

You may use any valid name instead of `@sql` and `stmt`.