# Removing duplicate rows and filling/updating value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, duplicates

I have table in SQL Server with many columns (NOT NULL)

```
CREATE TABLE Employee ( 
    [ID] INT identity(1,1), 
    [FirstName] Varchar(100), 
    [LastName] Varchar(100), 
    [Country] Varchar(100), 
    [ColumnX] Varchar(100), 
    [ColumnY] Varchar(100), 
)
    
Insert into Employee ([FirstName],[LastName],[Country],[ColumnX],[ColumnY] )
values('Raj','Gupta','India','','11'),
    ('Raj','Gupta','India','bb',''),
    ('Mohan','Kumar','USA','',''),
    ('James','Barry','UK','',''),
    ('James','Barry','UK','','22'),
    ('James','Barry','UK','aa','');

SELECT * FROM Employee;
```

I would like to remove the duplicate rows.
Table after removing duplicates and adding/merging values

| FirstName | LastName | Country | ColumnX | ColumnY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Raj | Gupta | India | bb | 11 |
| Mohan | Kumar | USA |  |  |
| James | Barry | UK | aa | 22 |

I would like to use a SQL query to remove duplicate rows, but unique values should remain only for selected columns, in this example for the first three columns.
The remaining columns should be completed, as in the example, with data from the second and next row - if they have a value.

I think I can't do it by keys, because one of the columns after which the rows will be deleted will be completed by an external user of the program.

In case of different values in a column for the same duplicates, you can take 'MAX' or merge 'CONCAT' or other solutions

I saw a similar problem - however there is an identification from duplicate rows after id
[SQL remove duplicates - keep the row with least missing value, and fill missing value from duplicate rows if any non-missing value exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70390130/sql-remove-duplicates-keep-the-row-with-least-missing-value-and-fill-missing)

My skills end with identifying duplicates
https://dbfiddle.uk/GrKB6Y-1

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you are overcomplicating this. You just need simple aggregation, with `MAX` and `COUNT`.

```sql
SELECT
  e.FirstName, 
  e.LastName, 
  e.Country,
  ColumnX = MAX(e.ColumnX),
  ColumnX = MAX(e.ColumnY),
  COUNT(*) AS DuplicateCount
FROM Employee e
GROUP BY
  e.FirstName, 
  e.LastName, 
  e.Country;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/eTB-TzpK)

Note that empty strings sort lowest, so will not be returned by `MAX` unless there is no other string.

If you actually want to delete rows from the base table then you can use window functions instead inside a CTE, and join it to a dummy table in a `MERGE`

```sql
WITH Target AS (
    SELECT
      e.ID,
      e.ColumnX,
      e.ColumnY,
      NewColumnX = MAX(e.ColumnX) OVER (PARTITION BY e.FirstName, e.LastName, e.Country),
      NewColumnY = MAX(e.ColumnY) OVER (PARTITION BY e.FirstName, e.LastName, e.Country),
      rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY e.FirstName, e.LastName, e.Country ORDER BY e.ID)
    FROM Employee e
)
MERGE Target t
USING (VALUES(1)) s(dummy)
ON 1=1
WHEN MATCHED AND t.rn > 1
  THEN DELETE
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
  SET ColumnX = t.NewColumnX,
      ColumnY = t.NewColumnY
;
```